# Parse incoming JSON (from javascript Ajax post) using Web API controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have the following script

```js
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        var model = [
            {
                "reservation":
                {
                    "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                    "clubId": 70656,
                    "courtNumber": 1,
                    "crud_name": "add",
                    "reservationtype_name": "toernooi"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "reservation":
                {
                    "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                    "clubId": 70656,
                    "courtNumber": 1,
                    "crud_name": "update",
                    "reservationtype_name": "toernooi"
                }
            }
        ];
        alert(JSON.stringify(model));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            url: "http://localhost:59854/api/incomingapi",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) { },
            error: function (errResult) { }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have the following controller

```cs
public string Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string jsonString1 = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var v1 = json_serializer.DeserializeObject("{ \"test\":\"some data\" }");
    var v2 = json_serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString1);
    JObject jobj1 = JObject.Parse("{ \"test\":\"some data\" }");
    JObject jobj2 = JObject.Parse(jsonString1);
    return "";
}
```

`v1` and `jobj1` are used for testing. The `jsonString1` is filled with values. The `v2` is filled with values at runtime.

However I only have the 4 methods

- Equals()
- GetHashCode()
- GetType()
- ToString()

available when I am typing my code...

I have to cast the values in the `jsonString1` to a collection of type reservation or something some how which I can then loop or use linq, but when I try something like that the values don't get populated(everything is null or 0).

Example, below I can loop and use linq but the values are not populated(are 0 and 0 instead of 70656 and 1 ):

```cs
var parsedVar = json_serializer.Deserialize<ICollection<ReservationModelForJson>>(jsonString1);
var clubId = parsedVar.First().clubId;//is 0 should be 70656
var courtNumber = parsedVar.First().courtNumber;//is 0 should be 1
```

Anybody can solve this? Many thanks!

```cs
public class ReservationModelForJson
{
    public string ticketId { get; set; }
    public int clubId { get; set; }
    public int courtNumber { get; set; }
    public string crud_name { get; set; }
    public string reservationtype_name { get; set; }
}
```

ANSWER/SOLUTION:

I added the class below

```
public class JsonBinder
{
    public ReservationModelForJson reservation { get; set; }
}
```

And changed my controller into

```
public string Post(IEnumerable<JsonBinder> reservations)
{
    int clubId = reservations.First().reservation.clubId;
    int courtNumber = reservations.First().reservation.courtNumber;
    return "tnkx!";
}
```

Comment: Just create an object for the `Post()` method to accept and then instead of passing `JSON.stringify()` pass the actual json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your deserialization is failing. What your trying to deserialize on the server side doesn't match up with your json model. Currently your trying to deserialize a list of objects with property name reservation(which is a object with expected properties). To fix, remodel your json like below.

```
 var model = [
        {
                "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                "clubId": 70656,
                "courtNumber": 1,
                "crud_name": "add",
                "reservationtype_name": "toernooi"
        }, 
        {
                "ticketId": "782274b8-10d9-444c-8f05-3117853e3ee0",
                "clubId": 70656,
                "courtNumber": 1,
                "crud_name": "update",
                "reservationtype_name": "toernooi"
        }
    ];
```

Or create a class with an object property name reservation that has expected properties, ticketId, clubId, etc...

Comment: Thank you and everybody else! I cann't change the Json format so the last option worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
json_serializer.Deserialize<List<ReservationModelForJson>>(jsonString1);
```

And your properties like  `courtNumber` are in `reservation` object so for example you should use like `parsedVar.First().courtNumber;`. Structure of `ReservationModelForJson` matters in this case.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work...Also tried `IEnumerable` and `ICollection`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Instead of the HttpRequestMessage argument in your Post method, use a collection of ReservationModelForJson. Also, you will probably need to remove the JSON.stringify(model), and just pass the model.

```
public string Post(IEnumerable<ReservationModelForJson> reservations)
{
   //Now you can work with the reservations collection
   var firstRes = reservations.FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: It is my believe too this should work, but somehow it doesn't. I tried passing just the `model` and using `JSON.stringify(model)`